# Angular project CI in azure devops giving error 'Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: '

Tags: angular, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I was applying CI/CD in one of my project which hosted in GitHub. The project divided into two subfolders in one of them consists in asp.net core web API project and other is an angular project. I have successfully built ci/cd for the asp.net core project but when I was building ci/cd for the angular project the CI portion giving an error with

```
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found 
PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/dist
```

My pipline yml script was:

```
    trigger:
    - master

    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        pushd tritronFrontend
        npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.8
        npm install
        ng build 
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'dist'
      ArtifactName: 'dist'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

But when I saw some tutorial in the internet and there was a suggestion for adding archive file section as below:

```
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile:'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
```

But this was triggering error that was

```
    ##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found 
    PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/dist
```

I have already tried with adding archive file section but it did not work.

Comment: What is the logs of the `ng build` step? probably the `dist` folder exist in deeper folder.

Comment: the project is public so build log can be found here https://dev.azure.com/fahimabrar/tritronv2/_build/results?buildId=119

Comment: try to change the "PathToPublish" to `trintonFrontend\dist`

Comment: already tried did it gives error                                                                                                    Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/trintonFrontend\dist

Comment: Should be `ng build --prod`

Comment: --prod is for production mode only.  Ng build also create dist folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone wants to deploy an angular app that is in any specific folder on github he have to pushd those specific angular folder in my case i have solved my problem with below likes script:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    pushd tritronFrontend
    npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.8
    npm install
    npm run build
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'tritronFrontend/dist'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 2):

using this code instead:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: exited with error code 254 https://dev.azure.com/fahimabrar/tritronv2/_build/results?buildId=125

Comment: @lazyfahim Specify workingDirectory. Check the updated code.

Comment: what will be the working directory? the projects is actually inside a folder. you can check here https://github.com/lazyfahim/tritronv2/tree/master/tritronFrontend

Comment: @lazyfahim It is use to specify task's context. The package.json is in root folder, so the working directory is $(Build.SourcesDirectory). Check predefined variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables

Comment: it gives error  ##[error]Bash exited with code '254'.
##[section]Finishing: npm install and build https://dev.azure.com/fahimabrar/tritronv2/_build/results?buildId=135

Comment: @lazyfahim It is the same issue. I checked your latest build, it works fine.

Comment: in the latest build i have added pushd tritronFrontend and for the build release not working

Comment: latest build was trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    pushd tritronFrontend
    npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.8
    npm install
    npm run build
    ng build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'angular'
    targetPath: 'tritronFrontend/dist'

Comment: @lazyfahim So, do you have issue now?

Comment: i have solved the issue by adding 'tritronFrontend/dist' and pushd command.thank you for the help